# Sitecore 8.1 WFFM rev. 151008 does not work with MVC

Tags: wffm

I am using Sitecore.NET 8.1 rev. 151003. On top of it I am installing Web Forms for Marketers 8.1 rev. 151008

As that is working perfectly with Webforms it doesn't with MVC 5.

When I submit a simple form then it shows me success message and the whole page loads within the same page. It means that it returns full page in the form section and I end up with my website design distorted with 2 headers, 2 footers etc.

So I have problem:

How can I prevent WFFM from returning the whole page in the form area.

Comment: Can you please describe what your custom js does? What custom libraries does it use?

Comment: Hi @SzymonKuzniak,
Actually I just include jquery library file that is stored locally ,means i am not using sdn for that .

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue and we could solve it to switch off the `Is Ajax Mvc Form` on the form items in Sitecore.

[image]